# Is there a better/more efficient way to get next/previous row when sorting on non-unique columns?

Tags: php, mysql

So the problem is this:

There is a list of items that have properties. In my case it is a list of works of art. They have a title, belong to a category, are made in a certain year and are of a specific medium. Example:

```
id |  title  |  category   |  year  |   medium  
_______________________________________________
 1 |  Work1  |  painting   |  2014  |   canvas
 2 |  Work2  |  painting   |  2009  | aluminium
 etc. etc.
```

In my front-end I list all the items sorted on either year, title or category. Depending on which sorting is used for the list I want different next and previous links displayed when viewing individual items because they are of course different depending on the sorting of the list.

I first tried this(for next)

```
SELECT * FROM work WHERE $sorting_row > $value_from_current_item ORDER BY $sorting_row ASC LIMIT 1;
```

But this gave problems when there were more items with the same value that was sorted on. The next and previous items shown did not coincide with the previous and next in the list.

My solution now is I pass the sorting in the url so i have for example:

```
www.example.com/front/work/detail/6/year
```

which in this case means the detail method in the front/work controller gets passed the id (6) and the sorting of the list it came from (year). Now i query the DB for the entire list, and iterate over it like this: (this is the one for previous, it uses codeigniter's active record for querying the db)

```
 get_previous ($id, $sort){
$previous_id = null;
             // only query for known columns
            if ($sort == 'title' || $sort == 'year' || $sort == 'category') {
                // Get array of works in the selected order
                $this->db->from($this->_table);
                $this->db->order_by($sort, 'asc');
                $this->db->where('published', 1);
                $result = $this->db->get();
                $result_array = $result->result_array();

                // If empty set is returned, $previous_id is not altered from null
                if (count($result_array) > 0) {
                    // Starts from 2nd record as the first has no previous.
                    for ($i = 1; $i < count($result_array); $i++) {

                        // if $id is found, get the id of the previous record in array and set $previous_id
                        if ($result_array[$i]['id'] == $id) {
                            $previous_id = $result_array[$i - 1]["id"];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    return $previous_id;
  }
```

Now fetching the entire set everytime you just want just the next and previous record seems overkill, but I have not been able to come up with an alternative (also not in the posts about previous/next rows here on SO). So hence the question:

Is this very inefficient, and if so, what would be the better alternative?
(the obvious is ofcourse getting one method to get both previous and next, so the query is run only once, which I am doing atm)

Thanks for any input!

Comment: you will want to use MySQL `LIMIT` also look into pagination

Comment: do you mean, yes this is very inefficient, so look into `LIMIT` and pagination?